# How to log in in with Selenium when automation of moving letters is needed

Tags: java, selenium

I am creating a script in order to access a website using a username and a password and I am using Selenium Webdriver. The problem is that, for authentication, except for the email and password fields there is also a field with moving letters which need to be introduced.
The link to the website is [here](https://login.comcast.net/login?forceAuthn=1&continue=%2FSecure%2FHome.aspx&s=ccentral-cima&r=comcast.net).
Is there any way that this can be done with Selenium?

Comment: that website is yours ??

Comment: No, it is a public website

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-solve-captcha-image-selenium-chetna-soni

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done. "Moving letters" is an mechanism to determine whether or not the user is human.

[Read more.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA)